What Items Give Bonuses to Charisma Ability Checks?
I am thinking about dipping into Sorcerer so I can have the ability to cast scrolls. However, in order to cast scrolls higher than 1st level, I'd have to pass an ability check in order to do so.
Aside from Luckstone, what other items give bonuses to charisma ability checks (since I’ll be using sorcerer)? "Bonuses" in this case can come in the form of numeric increases, ability to roll with advantage, or any other this that will make it more likely for me to succeed in said check.

As a sorcerer trying to cast spell scrolls, charisma ability check boosting items are what you’re looking for, and we already have a question on that. I’ve closed this as a duplicate.
